# a priori constant calculation

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'd like to define a constant integer as a result of simple +-*and/ operations during compilation. I tried this using `const double XMIN = ..` but this does not allow the use of other constant in its right hand side. So I cannot make the following definitions:

```
#define SEED_GRAIN 1e5
#define XMIN -0.2f 
#define XMAX 0.2f
#define XLENGTH (XMAX-XMIN)
#define XRAND ((XLENGTH*SEED_GRAIN)+1)
```

as a priori calculation of the interval numbers for a random number, which I use as follows:

```
x = rand()%(int)XRAND;
x = pt.x/SEED_GRAIN + XMIN;
```

This works under some C compiler on  Mac, but Windows SDK complains about the `(int)XRAND` line in the following way:

```
error C2105: '--' needs l-value
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
```

I guess all of this can be done somehow with constants instead of those ugly compiler definitions, but I haven't got the deep understanding of when something is regarded as constant expression for the compiler. Can someone guide me the way to a clean solution?
Fwiw I'm compiling a mex file in matlab and as explained it works on mac with the standard compiler and `mex -O CFLAGS='\$CFLAGS -std=c11' main.c` but refuses to compile under windows with sdk 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put integer- and float-literals in parenthesis when using them with `#define`s.

```
#define SEED_GRAIN (1e5)
#define XMIN (-0.2f) 
#define XMAX (0.2f)
```

Alternatively you could do

```
const double sees_grain = 1e5;
const double xmin = -0.2f;
const double xmax = 0.2f;
```

If needing them on global level for the two other ones there is no way around but doing:

```
#define XLENGTH (xmin - xmax)
#define XRAND ((XLENGTH * seed_grain) + 1.)
```

of just define and initialise them on run-time by doing

```
double xlength = 0.;
double xrand = 0.;

int main(void)
{ 
  xlength = xmin - xmax;
  xrange = (xrange * seed_grain) + 1.;

  ...
```

Comment: There is no global need to have them, but I want them to be computed at compile-time.

Comment: @mike: You are correct, they "*cannot be calculated on compile-time*". I am a slow typer ... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I'll stick to my Prepocessor constants (which are now working).

Answer (score 4):

The cause is that `(XMAX-XMIN)` will expand to `(XMAX--0.2f)` and then `--` is seen as an operator and not as `- -0.2f`.